# jQuery fly out div fails

Tags: jquery, html, web

I've started writing my own Jquery.  I'm right at the very beginning at the minute and practicing hiding divs then making them visible again.  So at the beginning I'm hiding the div's through Jquery

```
 $(".hidden-div1").hide();  
 $(".hidden-div2").hide();
```

I have then made the basic div's and followed a tut for how to use slideToggle.

```
$("#show1").click(function () {
    $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#show2").click(function () {
    $(".hidden-div2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

So I have 2 links on the page and 2 hidden div's.  They work fine and slide out and hide as they should according to the slidetoggle.

However,  one of the links is halfway down my page.  When its clicked not only does it slide out the hidden div (as it should) but it jumps to the very top of the website.  I then have to scroll down to see the new div.  My question is this.  How do I stop the jump to the top of the page upon clicking the link?  I can post a link to the site if my question makes no sense.

Thanks Stackers

Comment: "I've started writing my own Jquery." - sounds promising :)

Comment: @cherniv lol nothing like starting again.  learnt "hello world" last night ;)

Comment: Post a fiddle so we can see what you did.

Comment: @aiapatag oooo ok I never done that.  It may not show what I mean though as it will already be at the top of the page but ok I will

Comment: @aiapatag Here is my fiddle but it does not represent whats wrong http://jsfiddle.net/9rtvs/

Comment: I guess this is more like it: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/9rtvs/1/
And it is a css issue...

Comment: @BalintBako no thats not the problem. http://komodo.yourarena.co.uk/index3.php#  click the second more info link and you will see

Comment: the same working fine in your fiddle, right? then why? its not working in your browser?

Comment: Hi @Delphian  yes it works ok but if you click the link above and go to the site then click the second more info section you will see.  Instead of the div scrolling down it jumps to the top of the site.  You then have to scroll down from there.  The page should expand below where you are instead

Comment: I see, you should have started with this :D Probably the default event on the link is called on your website, which is the page and a #, so it will scroll up essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()` or use something else then an `<a>` element for the button.
Check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/9rtvs/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide some divs
    $(".hidden-div1").hide();

    $("#show1").click(function (event) {
        $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow");
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Comment: wicked @BalintBako that works too.  Thanks again for your help on this.  Now I understand you must overwrite the htmls default actions first or try to use another tag instead.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change

< a href="#" id="show2" class="morelinkwhite">Find Out More< /a>

to

< span id="show2" class="morelinkwhite">Find Out More< /span>

when you click link with # it refreshes the page and jumps to the top. Do it to all "Find Out More" buttons. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks that worked.  I understand now what was wrong.  Ill make sure I prevent the default action or not use links from now on.  Thanks again to everyone for the help!!!!